# How do I set up my network configuration for static IP address in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

My ISP has a static IP address. Therefore, whenever I use the guest machine in VirtualBox, I have to set the network to NAT. All other VMs get the same IP address. If I set network to *bridged*, I am unable to use the internet, presumably as a result of the static IP address. How can I set up my network more conveniently?

Comment: Don't you have a router in your network? Are you directly connected to your modem?

Answer (score 1):

A bridged network functions like a physical ethernet port. This is really useful if you're on a local network or if you've got multiple static IP addresses.

If you only have a single static IP address and it's already assigned to your computer, you won't be able to use bridged networking since there's no IP address to assign to it.

You'll have to use NAT in order to connect.

If you've got multiple IP addresses, bridged networking should work after you manually assign the address and proper network settings. The method should be the same as you did with your main computer. If your main computer was auto-assigned an IP address, it's probably a sign that you don't have multiple static addresses, as they probably would have been assigned by DHCP like your main computer.

Comment: and if i use NAT then all guest machines in virtual box gets the same ip add like 10.0.0...